# Creating custom buttons in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have my class, which should represent buttons (pads, if I need to be specific). Right now I am wondering if it's possible to draw them in my QMainWindow class.

In first version of app I created buttons in QtCreators designer. But right now I Would like to create them by code. As said before, already got class Pad, where I want to have position, text and other behaviors. Right now my class is pretty poor:

```
#include <QObject>

class Pad
{
   public:
   Pad(int x, int y);

 private:
   int m_xPosition;
   int m_yPosition;
};
```

And here is how I create them (where m_pads is std::vector )

```
void PadsWindow::createPads(const int &numberOfPads)
{
    enablePadsWindow();

    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfPads; ++index)
    {
        m_Pads.push_back(new Pad(10, 100));
    }  
}
```

Exactly here I would like to draw buttons in my QMainWindow and have it like normal QPushButton.

Could you help guys ?

Comment: You don't want to have to manually place every button. You want to use layouts to do that for you. You can inherit from `QPushButton` to make `Pad` look and behave like a regular button and can then change the look and behavior in `Pad`s constructor and `override`n `virtual` functions.

Comment: Additionally in the designer you can rightclick on a button you added and promote it to a `Pad`, so you can keep using the designer for placing `Pad`s.

Comment: In case you want everything as much custom as possible, you can inherit from `QWidget` and override `QWidget::paintEvent` and fill it with your own rendering logic. In order to catch mouse input, override `QWidget::mousePressEvent` and the other `QWidget::mouseXyzEvent` methods. You can then position such a widget using the usual layout mechanisms.

Answer (score 3):

To use a custom class as UI widget it must inherit from [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#details), which provides the necessary interface and already a lot of implementations (which you can override to customize the behaviour).

To make a widget behave like a button it is recommandable to use [`QAbstractButton`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html) or one of its derivations as base class, because these already provide much of the behaviour, and customizing is easier than adding all functionality to a plain `QWidget`.

This class can be added as custom widget to [Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html), so you can use it like any original Qt widget in dialogs and layouts.

You can find a lot of tutorials and FAQs regarding custom widgets on the net and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=qt+custom+widget), so getting started should be easy enough for anyone who's got a grasp of the basics of Qt and C++.